# Different ROS versions in turtlebot3

Tags: ros

I am currently working on turtlebot3 robot. which ROS version is suitable ? How different ROS version can effect my work? is it possible to use the version that has already met EOL date?

Answer (score 0):

Right now the [turtlebot3 package](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot3) has releases available for Kinetic, Melodic, and Noetic. None of the 3 releases will have really noticeable impacts on your work in the general sense. You can use an EOL distro, but it's really dependent on what OS you will be running.